# Find query with and operator in PHP

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

Hi i am working on backend of web application & want to find the documents from mongodb database that contain key active_status with value set to both 1 & 2. With mongodb PHP i am confused of how to find with both parameters in single query.

My query was this:

```
$mongoDb = MongoDbConnector::getCollection("endusers");
$endUserData = $mongoDb->find(array('active_status' => 1, '$and' => array('active_status' => 2)));
```

I have to fetch the users whose active_status should be 1 & 2. The above query doesnt seems to work. What is the right one for that?

Thanks on advance for quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You have [`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/and/) the wrong way around. Both arguments need to be included:

```php
$endUserData = $mongoDb->find(array(
   '$and' => array( 
       array( 'active_status' => 1 )
       array( 'active_status' => 2 )
   )
));
```

And since that would only make sense when looking for both elements within an array element, then you should instead use [`$all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/all/), which is shorter syntax:

```php
$endUserData = $mongoDb->find(array(
    'active_status' => array( '$all' => array(1,2) )
));
```

I should add that unless you intend to match a document like this:

```php
{ "active_status" => [1,2] }
```

The you do not in fact want `$and` at all, but rather you want [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/or/) or better yet [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/) for multiple possible values on the same field:

```php
$endUserData = $mongoDb->find(array(
    'active_status' => array( '$in' => array(1,2) )
));
```

This matches documents like this:

```php
{ "active_status": 1 },
{ "active_status": 2 }
```